# Is there a sphere parallel line?

Tags: geometry

What are straight lines? On the plane, straight lines are the locus of the point where the direction of motion does not change.

On the sphere, we can regard any given circle as the circle of latitude (the equator is a special circle of latitude). The point along the circle of latitude movement, is the east-west direction of movement, that is, the movement does not change direction. So circles on the sphere are straight lines . Great circles are straight lines, and small are straight lines.

So, circles are all straight lines on the sphere. Thus, through a given point, only one line can be drawn parallel to a given line.

On the sphere, what is the tangent of the circle of latitude? The tangent of the circle of latitude is the circle of latitude itself. So the slope of circle of latitude equals zero. On the plane, the slope of the straight line parallel to the X axis of the coordinate is equal to zero.

Comment: As has been told to you in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2521393/is-the-small-circle-the-straight-line-on-the-sphere), _only the great circles_ are straight on a sphere. The blue curves on [this picture](https://sciencevspseudoscience.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/latitude_longitude.png) are _not straight_. Only the red ones (and _one_ of the blue ones, the equator) are.

Comment: If you allow "small circles" to be "straight lines" on a sphere there are circles which do not meet and it is quite easy to construct transversals which don't cross them at right-angles and which contradict your purported parallel property.

Comment: "If a straightline intersects two straightlines forming two interior angles on the same side that sum to less than two right angles, then the two straightlines, Close to each other on that side on which the angles sum to less than two right angles."  This is not a sentence.  Then the two straightlines do what?

Comment: "the straight lines is circles on a sphere, the great circles and small circles are all straight lines."  If I defined straight lines as being Panda Bears then I could prove that straight lines eat bamboo.  Would that be useful to you?

Comment: Wickipedia about "straight lines" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)#In_projective_geometry " In the spherical representation of elliptic geometry, lines are represented by ***great circles*** of a sphere with diametrically opposite points identified."  The lesser circles are ***NOT*** straight lines.

Comment: If lesser circles are defined to be be straight lines, there will be no difference between spherical and plane geometries definitions of lines and circles.  Every condition of a small circle on a sphere applies to a small circle in a plane.  The parralel postulate does not apply to circles.

Comment: @arthurnov I didn't say the big circle wasn't straight, but I said the small one was straight, and I already said my reasons. Is my reason wrong? Why?

Comment: @Mark Bennet I have revised the question and welcome your comments.

Comment: @fleablood You see why I say the big circle and the small circle are straight lines.

Comment: @fleablood Wickipedia said, but this is equal to Wickipedia said is right.

Comment: @fleablood Plane geometry and spherical geometry are different, for example, the spherical angle and plane angle are different, not intersect on the sphere, not parallel, and so on.

Comment: @enbinzheng: Two different axiomatic characterizations of the straight lines: (1) Two points determine one an only one straight lines. (only partial characterization) (2) The shortest path between two points is the straight. The small circles do not meet these conditions.

Comment: ‪ ‬@zoli ‪see in questions according to what I say small circles are the straight lines. Can you tear down my foundation? ‬

Comment: Yes, small circles constantly change direction. At a point on a small cir l

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't finish... so the small circles change direczion... the concept of  direction is tied to the concept of the vector. The concept of a vector is tied to patallelism. The circle is closed here.

Comment: @zoli So, do you understand the circle of latitude? Does the circle of latitude represent the east-west direction?

Comment: @MarkBennet Because small circles are straight lines, so on the sphere, if two straight lines are parallel, then when they are transected by a straight line, they have the same collocation angle and the same internal misalignment angle. Do you think I am wrong?

Comment: @fleablood Because small circles are straight lines, so on the sphere, if two straight lines are parallel, then when they are transected by a straight line, they have the same collocation angle and the same internal misalignment angle. Do you think I am wrong?

Comment: @zoli Because the curvature of the small circle and the big circle of the sphere is zero, so I say that the big circle and the small circle are spherical straight lines.

Comment: Good Grief!  Not you again!  Go away.   No, you are "not even wrong".  You are not smart enough to be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Let alone that small circles are not straight lines on the sphere, and put the OP's statement the following way:

Consider two great circles $a$ and $b$ that are intersected by a third one, $c$. Let the "interior angles" be denoted by $M$ and $N$ and let $M+N<2R$. $a$ and $b$ will meet on the side at which the sum of the angles is less the $2R$ ($Q$). So the Euclidean parallel postulate is met on the sphere. As shown below.

[image]

If one looks at the figure the one will discover that the straight lines meet at $L$ as well. That is, on the side at which the sum of the external angles $M'+N'$ is greater than $2R$.

The essence of the parallel postulate is that the straights at stake meet on *that* side at which the sum of the angles... and not on the  the side at which...

If we consider the opposite points to be the same, as it is done in spherical geometry then the expression "on that side"  will loose its meaning because the straight lines meet on booth sides of $c$ in the same point that can be called $QL$.

So, the Euclidean postulate of parallels is not met on the surface of the sphere.

Comment: “If we consider the opposite points to be the same, as it is done in spherical geometry…” – you mean [*elliptic* geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_geometry), right?

Comment: @MvG: right. Right. 15 chars...

Comment: @zoli Thank you for your detailed answer. I've revised my question. I hope you'll continue to comment.

Comment: @zoli You only consider the big circle, but the small circle is straight line, so the parallel exists, on the sphere.

Comment: The small circles are not straight lines: two points do not determine an exact small circle. (They determine one great circle!)

Comment: @zoli Small circles are not straight lines, this is a false idea.

Comment: @zoli Sorry, my question has been modified, and you can see what I said on the top floor.